# Kendo chart second valueAxis issue, not working with axisCrossingValue

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo chart with two valueAxes.

- One valueAxis is all positive values
- other can have negative

Range defined in chart is based on the values. I want both the valueAxis to have value "0" as axisCrossingValue.

I tried this with axisCrossingValue but it is not respecting this value for second valueAxis.

```
var data1 = [6000, 8000];
var data2 = [0.2, -0.3] ;
$scope.chartOptions = {
    transitions: false,
    legend: {
        visible: false
    },
    chartArea:
    {
        margin: {
            left: 20,
            right: 20
        },
        background: "transparent"
    },
    seriesDefaults: {
        type: "column"
    },
    series: [
        {
            type: "column",
            stack: true,
            name: "A",
            color: "#efefef",
            axis: "A",
            highlight: {
                visible: false
            },
            data: data1
        }, {
            type: "line",
            name: "B",
            color: "#008700",
            axis: "B",
            style: "smooth",
            markers: {
                visible: false,
                border: {
                    width: 0
                }
            },
            data: data2
        }
    ],
    valueAxes: [
        {
            name: "A",
            labels: {
                visible: true,
                template: "#= kendo.format('{0:n}', value) #",
                color: "#888"
            },
            axisCrossingValue: 0
        }, {
            name: "B",
            labels: {
                visible: true,
                justified: true,
                template: "#= value #",
                color: "#888"

            },
            axisCrossingValue: 0
        }
    ],
    categoryAxis: {
        labels: {
            visible: false
        },
        categories: $scope.dates,
        axisCrossingValues: [0, $scope.dates.length]
    },
    tooltip: {

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the chart does not know how to automatically handle crossing at 0 on both axes. I think your best bet is to calculate/set the min and max values of the 2 axes such that 0 is in the same place on both axes:

```
  valueAxis: [
    {
      name: "A", 
      axisCrossingValue: 0,
      min: -9000,
      max: 9000,
      color: "#888",
      majorGridLines: {
        visible: false,
      }
    }, 
    {
      name: "B", 
      min: -0.5,
      max: 0.5,
      justified: true,
      color: "#888",
      majorGridLines: {
        visible: false,
      }    
    }
  ],
```

> **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/eTewI)**

Comment: this seems to be working but since my range is dynamic based on data(dynamic data) and to set the max/min some calculation will be required.

Comment: @ShardoolSingh, that is correct; you will have to calculate appropriate max and min values...

Answer (score 0):

To do this dynamically, I had to override the default max/min values for each axis with a rounded value calculated from my data sets.

```js
    $scope.getChartMaxMin(values, percentages) {

            var minValue = 0;
            var maxValue = 0;    
            var minPercent = 0;
            var maxPercent = 0;

            angular.forEach(values, function (val) {    
                if (val < minValue) {
                    minValue = val;
                }
                if (val > maxValue) {
                    maxValue = val;
                }
            })

            angular.forEach(percentages, function (percent) {
                percent = percent * 100;    
                if (percent < minPercent) {
                    minPercent = percent;
                }
                if (percent > maxPercent) {
                    maxPercent = percent;
                }
            })

            minValue = intelliRound(Math.floor(minValue));
            maxValue = intelliRound(Math.ceil(maxValue));    
            minPercent = intelliRound(Math.floor(minPercent));
            maxPercent = intelliRound(Math.ceil(maxPercent));

            var difference = maxValue / maxPercent;
            minPercent = minValue / difference;    

            return {
                minValue: minValue,
                maxValue: maxValue,
                minPercent: minPercent,
                maxPercent: maxPercent
            }   
        }
        function intelliRound(num) {
            var len = (num + '').length;
            var result = 0;
            if (num < 0) {
                var fac = Math.pow(10, len - 2); 
                result = Math.floor(num / fac) * fac;
            }
            else {
                var fac = Math.pow(10, len - 1);
                result = Math.ceil(num / fac) * fac;
            }
            return result;
        }

        var values = [40000, 60000, -30000]    
        var percentages = [3.65,0.010,1.69]    
        var maxMin = $scope.getChartMaxMin(values, percentages);    

    $scope.chartOptions = {   

        series: [
            {
                type: "column",
                stack: true,
                name: "A",
                color: "#efefef",
                axis: "A",
                highlight: {
                    visible: false
                },
                data: values
            }, {
                type: "line",
                name: "B",
                color: "#008700",
                axis: "B",
                style: "smooth",
                markers: {
                    visible: false,
                    border: {
                        width: 0
                    }
                },
                data: percentages
            }
        ],
        valueAxes: [
            {
                name: "A",
                labels: {
                    visible: true,
                    template: "#= kendo.format('{0:n}', value) #",
                    color: "#888"
                    min: maxMin[minValue],
                    max: maxMin[maxValue] 
                },
            }, {
                name: "B",
                labels: {
                    visible: true,
                    justified: true,
                    template: "#= value #",
                    color: "#888"
                }, 
                min: maxMin[minPercent],
                max: maxMin[maxPercent]           
            }
        ],
        categoryAxis: {
            labels: {
                visible: false
            },
            categories: $scope.dates,
            axisCrossingValues: [0, $scope.dates.length]
        },    
    };
```